# Is adding primary key secondary index of mysql is redundant?

Tags: mysql

I have been looking into indexing my mysql database (InnoDb) for various use-cases and query patterns.
For example the sample db table (Employee) has following columns.

```
EmployeeId, name , reporting_manager,  addedOn , deletedOn
```

Here the primary key is EmployeeId.
I wanted to add indexes on addedOn column to for some usecase to list the users added based on time etc. The following would be query pattern we have our usecase.

```
select * from Employee where addedOn > (?)
```

```
select * from Employee where addedOn > (?) and EmployeeId is in ('1', '2', '3')
```

I am thinking two kind of indexes here in this case

1. addedOn
2. addedOn_EmployeeId

I am thinking of index alone on addedOn column but not with both addedOn&EmployeeId. The reason behind is that , mysql might build index implicitly which might point to EmployeeId.
I am not sure if am thinking in right direction and missing some basics.

Question:

1. What is main difference between both the indexes internal to mysql?
2. Will having first one solve all the query patterns i described above ?

Comment: *For example the sample db table (Employee) has following columns.* This tells about nothing. Provide **complete** CREATE TABLE script.

Comment: Please add to your question the output of: `show create table Employee;`

Comment: 1. Primary key is clustered index on InnoDB. Rather than secondary index. 2. Index addedOn_EmployeeId won't work completely, it will use index seek by addedOn then index scan by EmployeeId.